# Run once if x but twice if not x

Tags: c#, loops, int, logic

This is my current code:

```
int max;
if(runOnce)
    max = 1;
else
    max = 2;

for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    //do stuff
```

It looks very messy and I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why this looks messy? Looks good for me. You can reduce it by `int max = runOnce? 1 : 2;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

`for (int i = 0; i < (runOnce? 1 : 2); i++)`

Comment: How about something that compiles.

Comment: @pierre-lucpineault it compiles fine. tried it with c++ compiler. http://ideone.com/cj7E0k

Comment: however, I missed enclosing the ternary operator inside parenthesis .. corrected it.

Comment: Now that's better. Always try your code before you post it. And btw this is C#, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to get rid of the `for`-loop, a simple solution would be to wrap up your 'do stuff' logic in a method:

```
private void DoStuff() 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

And then when you want to call it just do something like this:

```
DoStuff();
if (!runOnce) 
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

Alternatively, if you need access to a number local variables, you may want to consider using a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) instead of a method:

```
Action doStuff = () => 
{
    // do stuff
};

doStuff();
if (!runOnce) 
{
    doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Yep, in my opinion that's the best way to do it. You get rid of the magic numbers and a whole `for` loop that does not make sense if you run it only once. Personally I'd also change `!runOnce` to `runTwice` to avoid a negative condition, but that's that's just me

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
int max = (runOnce==true) ? 1 : 2;
for(i=0; i<max; i++)
```

The `?` operator is called conditional operator and it's general form is the following:

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

If the `condition` is true, then the `first_expression` is used. Otherwise the `second_expression` is used.

For more documentation please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Last but not least as Sriram pointed out in the comments, we can use also the

```
int max = runOnce ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: `int max = runOnce? 1 : 2` is more than enough :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel sure thing. But I wanted to be more readable for users that haven't used it before. I will update my post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's sometimes useful to know is that a boolean `true`, when converted to an integer, always has the value of `1`.  So this should work:

```
for( int i = (int)runOnce; i < 2; ++i )
```

It either counts (0, 1) if `runOnce` is false, or when it is true, skips 0, and runs only with i = 1.